# (1) A flight has a 1% chance of crashing. (2) It's scheduled to fly 200 flights that week. Does (2) add any info re: your risk?

Tags: survival, reliability, conditional-expectation, hazard

And assuming that:

a) This is that particular airplane's very first flight, ever (not just for the week).

b) Any distributions involved should be discrete in the sense that they should be functions of *n*, the discrete number of flights that it has flown so far- not functions of (continuous) total time flown, or miles flown, etc. Each flight = one flight; all flights are equivalent.

c) From the wording of the question, we don't know if the plane has a constant hazard function or if it experiences wear on its parts that increase its risk of crashing with each additional flight it takes. I suppose I'd like to know the answer in either scenario, but understand that the question may not have a well-defined answer in one, or both, scenarios.

I realize this question may be ill-defined or unanswerable. I came across it watching an interview with Nate Silver, the fellow who predicted the Obama/Romney election results with great accuracy, apparently. I don't have any experience working with reliability distributions or censored/truncated data, which is probably why I found it vexing even though it may come across as trivial or even silly to those who know more on the subject. My immediate instinct was that the answer is 'no,' regardless of whether the hazard function is constant or not- if it is constant, then the risk of each of the (scheduled) 200 flights going down would be independent random variables, defined by some distribution, so that to infer added information from (2) would be (perhaps?) some variation of the gambler's fallacy. If it is not constant, and wear and tear *does* increase the risk of each sequential flight going down, then still it should not matter according to the phrasing of the question, because you are on the very first flight.

But then.. I started thinking of it in terms of a conditional distribution, where the random variables representing the risk of each sequential flight crashing *are* dependent, because the risk of each one going down is conditional on whether or not the plane has crash on any of the previous flight (and assuming that there is no possibility of repairing or re-flying the plane after a crash). If the plane crashed on flight #34, then the probability that it should crash on flight #104, or #58, or obviously anything above #34, is zero.

But then, is that actually true, or am I misapplying the fundamental idea of conditional probability? In the sense that, once the plane crashes, its probability of crashing on any later flight is not zero, but undefined, since it no longer exists?

I'm almost certain that I'm wrong in one or multiple ways and would really love to be educated on how to interpret this properly. My final thought was that it all depends on the interpretation of the question, which, I think anyway, is worded somewhat vaguely. To wit, it would depend on whether you're looking at the chance of, say, flight #72 crashing *before* any of the flights have been flown- in other words, the probability it will be *that* particular flight that crashes, out of all 200; or on the other hand, if flight #71 has just landed safely as the gate, and you're now looking at the chance it will crash on its very next flight, which of course is #72.

As you, the passenger, is there any sense in which knowing you're a) on the very first flight; and b) that the "1% chance that your flight will go down" figure was given to you with the added condition that they are *expecting* it to fly 200 flights (let's just assume total, instead of 'that week') - does that, in some Bayesian sense, change the likelihood function of one more parameters of the survival/hazard distributions that may be involved? Does it change your *belief* at all, that your particular flight will crash, knowing that they calculated their 1% risk assesment based on a total of 200 flights, as opposed to, say, 1 flight? i.e., yours is the only flight it will ever take? Am I at all right in my guess that this involves conditional-*expectation*, as opposed to conditional probability?

Again, probably a very simple problem for many here, or more likely one that is ill-posed and/or admits no sensible answer, being a nonsense question- but it is nonetheless eating away at me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not well posed. When are you supposed to take the flight ? At the beginning of the week (first flight) ? Somewhere in the week ? At the end of the week ?

Let's assume we are taking the last flight of the plane. Now, you still have two ways of asking the question:

- What is the probability that the plane crashes at the 200th flight?

It should be less than 1% since, if the plane crashed before, it won't crash at the 200th flight.

- Given that it went through 199 flights, what is the probability that it crashes at the 200th flight?

It should still be 1%.

Now, if you add up a non-constant hazard rate (I just assumed that "the plane crashes" followed a Bernoulli distribution) the answer can be pretty much anything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. I can't argue the question is well-posed, I figured it likely wasn't. I did state in the full question though (i.e., the actual body of the post, rather than just the header) that I was asking the question with the supposition that you are not only boarding the first flight of the week's 200 flights, but also the very first flight that plane has ever flown. I added this bit, having heard the question asked in an interview (by a non-statistician). My question was only, knowing that the 1% figure was calculated based on an [expected] 200 flights,

Comment: does that add any information that you could conceivably use in any meaningul way? To make it as straightforward as possible: if you were told "This plane has never flown- this is its first, and ONLY flight. You have a 1% chance of crashing on the flight." - Would that be any different, in terms of your belief re: your risk, than if the statement were identical BUT that you were told the plane would fly 1,000,000 flights in its lifetime? Does the latter fact (so many flights!) mean that you having a 1% chance going down on the first flight is less significant/reliable in any way? Or more so?

Comment: Again, maybe this is a straightforward 'gambler's fallacy'-type mistake that I'm making here, but again I keep getting caught up on the fact that the probability of it crashing by the 100th flight is not the same as it crashing by the 150th flight, because the former event precludes the latter from occurring, even if the probability is iid for any given flight. So, in a Bayesian sense, does knowing the total number of flights the person telling you this based their calculation on in ANY way affect your belief in the reliability of this estimate? Or change its value in some strange way? Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: to the last part of the second comment I posted:

"Does the latter fact (so many flights!) mean that you having a 1% chance going down on the first flight is less significant/reliable in any way? Or more so?"

Should actually be:

"Does the latter fact (so many flights!) in any way affect the reliability or significange of the person's estimation of the probability as 1%? Does it in any way affect how much you believe in, or would rely upon, that figure?"

So, if this makes any sense at all, less of a frequentist approach, where 1% is a known parameter, and more of a Bayesian approach?